# How to dispose of a PrivateFontCollection correctly?

Tags: c#, interop, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

I'm using PrivateFontCollection to install uploaded fonts on my web server.  The code below works, but on second upload of a font the PrivateFontCollection references the first font uploaded.  So something isn't being disposed of correctly.  Anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
 var fontName = string.Empty;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(fontBytes))
    {
        // used to store our font and make it available in our app
        using (var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection())
        {
            //create memory pointer
            IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)ms.Length);

            try
            {
                //copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
                Marshal.Copy(fontBytes, 0, data, (int)ms.Length);

                // We HAVE to do this to register the font to the system (Weird .NET bug !)
                uint cFonts = 0;
                AddFontMemResourceEx(data, (uint)fontBytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref cFonts);

                //pass the font to the font collection
                pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)ms.Length);
                var fontWithMime = "data:application/x-font-truetype;charset=utf-8;base64," + cleanFontData;

                fontName = pfc.Families[0].Name;

                //db work here
            }
            finally
            {
                ms.Close();
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why a memory stream ? You don't seem to use it at all. Try the following trick: save the font to a temp file and use `PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile' to see if bug vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

PrivateFontCollection is a very flawed class and you have to be extremely careful using it.  A very gross bug in your existing code is the Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() call.  It is up to you to ensure that you do *not* call this function until *after* your code stops using *any* Font object you created from the family.  Failure to do so causes random glyph corruption, you only get an AccessViolationException if you are lucky.  Underlying problem is that the font will continue to use the memory you allocated with AllocCoTaskMem(), it is completely unaware that the memory is no longer valid.  Corruption occurs when the memory is re-used.

Furthermore, while the class has an AddMemoryFont() method, it does not have a corresponding RemoveMemoryFont() method.  The only way to clean up is by calling PrivateFontCollection.Dispose().  This deletes *all* of the fonts in the collection.  With the same stipulation as in the previous paragraph, you can only call Dispose() when you are sure that you no longer use any Font object.  Calling it too early does *not* cause an exception.

Very awkward behavior, only truly safe way to use the PFC is to keep it around for the life of the app.  Pretty painful in a web app of course.

You can assume that the added font is the *last one* in the FontFamily[] array.  Not the first one as you have it implemented now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [AddFontMemResourceEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To remove the fonts that were installed, call RemoveFontMemResourceEx.
>   However, when the process goes away, the system will unload the fonts
>   even if the process did not call RemoveFontMemResource.

However, I don't see you doing that. That might be the reason.